# How to set encoding attribute of XML prolog in JTidy?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jtidy

I need to generate XML from a HTML file with JTidy. The encoding of the source is GB2312, so I need to set the encoding of the generated XML to GB2312 as well.

Current XML prolog:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

What I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: current xml declaration: <?xml version="1.0"?>
what's i needed:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>

Comment: Please read the message formatting rules in editor's help, or just check the tooltips in editor's buttons. Also pay close attention to message preview area just below the editor if the formatting went all right. I have fixed it for you.

Comment: which editor?sorry i don't know what you mean.can you just show me some code?thanks!

Comment: Uh, I was talking about your question. I wasn't answering your question at all. Just trying to explain how to properly format code blocks in a post here. Your initial attempt has namely failed. Have you seen the edited question?